# where can I find relevant kubernetes yaml manifest files for specific hyperkube version?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, hyperkube

I'm trying to install kubernetes on my ContainerOS 1353.1.0 alpha by CoreOS.

I know that there are many scripts online to do that automatically but I don't want them I want to fully understand what's going on.

so at https://quay.io/repository/coreos/hyperkube?tab=tags there is `v1.6.0-rc.1_coreos.1`. lets say I wanna use that, where do I find the relevant manifest files to get things going? which means `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler` and `kube-proxy` yaml files. where do I find these?

I tried downloading kubernetes from github and compile it, but I found the relevant yaml files only in test directory.

so.... what am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most frustrating things about Kubernetes installations, they're basically abstracting the knowledge away from you to get things started. I understand your frustration.

First, be aware that Hyperkube is an all in one binary for all the Kubernetes components, so it's probably not the best way to understand what's going on. If you want to run Hyperkube, take a look at the `Dockerfile` in the [hyperkube repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/Dockerfile) to understand what's happening.

In a nutshell, what's happening is:

- The manifests (ie what Docker should run) [are being copied into a directory](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/Dockerfile#L42-L46), `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`
- [SSL configuration and Container networking (CNI)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/Dockerfile#L54-L66) are being set up
- The [HyperKube binary is being symlinked](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/Dockerfile#L74-L89) into the place where all the binaries are expected to be. This shows you all the components of Kubernetes. I would have a read of [this great article](https://x-team.com/blog/introduction-kubernetes-architecture/) which explains all of this more detail.

I would also highly recommend reading and following [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) by Kelsey Hightower, which will give you a much better understanding of how all this fits together.

Comment: it's not the first time I got assistance from you. thanks. this information helps me a lot. so if I understand correctly, the manifest files for the root kubernetes component are required only because of hyperkube usage? in other cases it's just a systemd service or something that ups the services ? is there a way to know the 'best' way to run these components so i'll write the manifests myself ?

Comment: The manifests that get dropped into the `/etc/kubernetes` directory will be executed by the `kubelet` binary. The kubelet is a binary that runs outside Docker (or in your case, rkt) and will simply read that directory for definitions and start some Docker containers. If you look at the example here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/static-pods/kube-proxy.json. All hyperkube does is mean you don't need to download 5 different binaries to run apiserver, controller, kubelet, etcd etc.

Comment: Hi! I probably don't explain myself properly or I miss something. where do I find the manifests files that get dropped into /etc/kubernetes ? do I create them myself? if I do, based on what?

Comment: If you're using hyperkube, you can find them in here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/static-pods. Alternatively you can have tools like `kubeadm` generate them, or as you say, you can generate them yourself. For example, if you look at the command line values for each components (like here https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/) you can configure them easily. I would recommend starting simple and working backwords, so maybe look at hyperkube or kubeadm first.

Comment: ahah.. I didn't know that you can use json manifests to install kubernetes components, not just yaml. now I understand your answer more properly :)